# How to Seal inside of sugar bowl with crazing

Tags: food-safety

i want to buy an antique sugar bowl but it has crazing and staining inside.  I want to be able to use it for sugar.  Is there something i can paint the inside with that is not going to be toxic? or is it OK to use the crazed sugar bowl as it is? it is not going to be subjected to heat or moisture.

Comment: A few questions to hopefully get you a better answer: Crazing as in a full crack, or as in cracking/ chipping of the glaze? And are you looking to preserve the original historic/ monetary value of the antique and do a temporary, restorative repair, or is functionality with an eye towards reusing existing pieces, even if this damages the original work, your primary purpose? — Also, would you be able to provide a picture to see the extent of the damage?

Comment: I just pinged the folks at [Arts & Crafts SE](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/), they’re probably more experienced with the preservation and restoration aspect than we are.

Comment: FWIW, speaking as a potter who sells functional pottery for food: it's fine.  Enjoy your sugar bowl.